# Capistrano thinks something is an error, it's not

Tags: ruby, capistrano, cloudflare

I have a capistrano deploy script that sends a curl request to cloudflare to purge the cache on each deploy.

Cloudflare responds with `sh: 1: {"result":{"id":"my_hidden_id_here"},"success":true,"errors":[],"messages":[]}: not found`

And capistrano thinks it's an error message, which it's not. Is there a way to tell it that this response is acceptable?

Comment: What is the http status code of cloudflare's response? 404 is an error

Comment: This looks like an error

Comment: @Yule @muzychuk It appears cloudflare returns it even though it's successful. Can see it in cloudflares logs in the backend, successful API calls that are successfully purging the cache. But in curl it's returning like malformed json. Shouldn't start with an `sh: 1:` or end with `not found` if success = true.

Comment: This could seem **off-topic**. Have you tried the [gem](https://github.com/gofullstack/capistrano-cloudflare) ?